# JsonDocument was not declared in this scope when delcaring a function

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to write a simple API view using ESP32 and Arduino IDE and I've run into this problem. When I declare a handler (function) the usual way, the compiler fails with `'JsonDocument' was not declared in this scope`, but when I split declaration and implementation, it works ok. What is causing it and how to work around it?

This fails:

```cpp
// Provides JsonDocument class
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void handleApi(JsonDocument& doc){}
```

This works:

```cpp
// Provides JsonDocument class
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void handleApi(JsonDocument& doc);
void handleApi(JsonDocument& doc){}
```